# custom xpath expression with tika

Tags: apache-tika

I am trying build custom xpath  contentHandler for tika that recognizes complex xpath expression,
by using code from org/apache/tika/sax/BodyContentHandler.java  (because I am using tika for other stuff)

This xpath works

```
/xhtml:html/xhtml:body/descendant:node()
```

but this does not

```
//xhtml:div[@id='someid']/descendant:node()
```

I want to integrate tika's contentHandler (because it fixes html contents unbalanced tags and invalid character) with xpath evaluator from javax.xml.xpath. What is a proper way of doing that. Is there a way I can get inputsource once tika has evaluated and fixed html content?

Answer (score 2):

The XPath feature included in Tika only supports a subset of XPath features (see [XPathParser](http://tika.apache.org/0.10/api/org/apache/tika/sax/xpath/XPathParser.html) for details). For more complex XPath queries I recommend using something like [javax.xml.xpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html).